# How to implement Facebook instant Article in laravel

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement facebook instant article in laravel application anyone guide me how can i implement this

I also found a package on GitHub [enter link description here](http://facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php)

but I don't know where to paste this code in laravel files

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using laravel and you've downloaded facebook SDK with composer, you don't have to paste this code anywhere. You can start using SDK already and import your articles

```
use Facebook\InstantArticles\Client\Client;

// Instantiate an API client
$ia_client = Client::create(
    'APP_ID',
    'APP_SECRET',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'PAGE_ID'
);

// Push the article to your Facebook Page
$ia_client->importArticle($my_article);
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/sdk/integration